# Is LLVM dependence analysis able to output dependence between two instructions other than store & load?

Tags: llvm, analysis

I am using llvm DependenceAnalysisWrapperPass to obtain the dependence between two IR instructions. But it seems like this analysis only output dependence between load/store instructions, but not say dependence between a load and a arithmetic instructions. Is there any pass in LLVM can output a more comprehensive dependence among instructions?

For example:

```
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  %r = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
  store i32 1, i32* %a, align 4
  store i32 2, i32* %b, align 4
  %0 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4
  %1 = load i32, i32* %b, align 4
  %add = add nsw i32 %0, %1
  store i32 %add, i32* %r, align 4
  %2 = load i32, i32* %r, align 4
  ret i32 %2
```

By using the DependenceAnalysisWrapperPass, it outputs the following dependency graph

[Dependency Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JWjS.jpg)

It shows that the two load instructions depend on the two store instructions, respectively. However it does not show the dependency between, say, the two load instructions and the following add instruction. This is expected, since the code of DependenceAnalysisWrapperPass says that it only shows the dependence between store and load instructions. My question is that is there any pass available showing other dependences as well?

Comment: LLVM uses SSA, ie. the dependencies are explicit: Each instruction depends on its operands and transitively on the operands of its own operands I think you need to elaborate the question, perhaps give an example to illustrate what you mean.

Comment: @arnt I have updated my post to include more information.

Answer (score 1):

The source code shows the information you want.

Each instruction's operands are precisely those instructions (or other values) on which it depends. This is a general principle of LLVM. The pass you've seen exists because loads and stores are an exception. However, loads and stores are the *only* exception.

Comment: Hello, do you mean I need to combine this pass and the user_begin(), user_end() for each instruction to get the complete dependencies?

Comment: Yes. However, note that DependenceAnalysisWrapperPass only gives approximate results. Memory allows inter-function dependencies, e.g. `bool a; bool b; void c() { a = !b;} void d() { a = true; b = true ; c(); if(a) {…` where the if depends on an unstruction in c() and that in turn depends on an instruction in d(). Memory is global.

Comment: Thanks. Right now I am handling a single function.